# How can I determine which of my questions have answers but have not had the "accepted answer" set?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, search

I would like to be able to search for or otherwise determine all questions I initiated which have one answer at least but which I have not selected a correct answer for.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: The questions in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116906/jonathanhayward?tab=questions) that have a number greater than 0 but which aren't yellow are questions with answer(s) but no accepted answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using the [search bar with custom filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A116906+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1)

```
user:116906 hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

- hasaccepted:no (looks for questions with no accepted answers)
- user:(id or me). To look for specific user
- answers:1 (for 1+ answers)

Comment: `is:question` isn't needed here.

Comment: @mattytommo true removed it, thanks to point it out.

Answer (score 3):

Use this search:

> user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1